# yarn link list all registered packages

Tags: yarnpkg

Yarn's [link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/) allows you to register a local package for symlinking into another local package.

however - I suspect one of the links is linking to the wrong package.

how can I list all the registered linked packages by yarn?
the [docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/) does not help

I'm using windows and i don't have `yarn` in my `~/.config` folder.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows you can find the linked packages at C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link

Answer (score 3):

On Linux: `/home/%username%/.config/yarn/link`

Or `ls -alh ~/.config/yarn/link/`